# Android Studio Autocompletion

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I've just switched to Android Studio and even with the few bugs I think its already much better than Eclipse. However there's on thing that annoys me. Can code like:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Implement
}
```

be autocompleted? So far when I start typing "public void onL" and press ^space I get no suggestions.

Also cmd enter (Generate) > Override Methods or Delegate Methods doesn't list this method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Start typing "onListItemClicked" and you should get auto complete suggestions after the first two letters.

Comment: So apparently if you type public void the autocompletion gets cancelled -_-

Comment: It makes sense, the problem is that I had to got to Google and Stack Overflow to figure that out.

Answer (score 9):

This happens if you write the @Override annotation before hand, android studio doesn't kick off the autocompletion. If you just start typing method name, it will inject everything for you, including the @Override annotation.

There may be other reasons why this happens, but this was the issue for me.

Comment: You are my hero. Was struggling from the start with this issue. Just because of having the habit of start typing @Override

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first check auto-completion settings. Go to File > Settings, then (under the IDE Settings category) you'll find Editor > Code Completion. Check that "Basic completion" and "Smart type completion" are checked (and you might as well have to check the "Autopopup code completion" checkbox).

Then if like me you coded for a long time on eclipse before making the switch to Android Studio (which is based on Intellij Idea), you'll probably like to get Eclipse shortcuts back. At the same "IDE Settings" level, go to "Keymap" and select the "Eclipse" option.

EDIT : you can also find Code completion settings and Keymap settings using the quick search bar at the top of the Settings screen.

Re-EDIT : About method declaration, I have them listed without issues... Not sure any of the Code completion settings can help you with that :|